# cakephp 3 - return object data from a function?

Tags: cakephp

I am just new to cakephp 3 and have the following issue: I am calling data from a soap source like this:

```
//connection to client...
$params = array('iban' => $iban);
$result = $this->client->validateIban($params);
```

So far so good.
I can debug the result too:

```
debug($result->validateIban);
```

it returns either 'true' or 'false'.

Now I want to return the value like this:

```
return $result->validateIban;
```

But I get now the error:

```
Controller action can only return an instance of Response
```

I am now a bit lost as I don't know how to return the value?
Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Where do you want to return the value?

Comment: Within a crontroller. I am also doing a jquery.post() to get the data to manipulate the view.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the right way:
As I am sending with jquery a post to the controller I need to send the value back as json:

```
$this->response->body(json_encode(array('iban' => $result->validateIban)));
return $this->response;
```